# How do I disable the Drag Fill/ Auto Fill on an IRange object for Spreadsheet Gear .NET?

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I am trying to disable the Drag Fill / Auto Fill functionality on spreadsheet gear IRange object, but have been unable to do so.

Is there a way to disable the Drag Fill / Auto Fill functionality ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WorkbookView class has an AllowEditCommands property that can be set to false to disable the various edit commands, including the AutoFill feature.  Of course, this command disables all other edit commands such as Cut, Copy, Paste, Undo, Redo, as well as some others.  Unfortunately, there currently is not a way to disable just AutoFill and still keep all these other commands enabled.  Feel free to contact us (I work for SpreadsheetGear) at sales@spreadsheetgear.com if you would like me to add your information to our feature request to support disabling only AutoFill.  I cannot say when we might implement this, but we would certainly contact you when we do move forward on it.

Comment: I ended up doing a workaround where on the appropriate event, I check the ActiveCommandManager.UndoDisplayText and call the ActiveCommandManager.Undo() if it has "Auto Fill" or just set e.Cancel = true;

Comment: @ashish.chettiar: might you post relevant code; I'm interested because I haced the same problem, but didn't found a proper solution :|